# how to use sql count() function multiple times in same table with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table:

| name | number | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 91104 | '2022-12-01' |
| name2 | 11161 | '2022-12-02' |

I am writing these queries:

```
select count(name) from table
    where
        created_at between
            '2022-12-01' and '2022-12-10' and
        terminal_id like '911%'
```

```
select count(name) from table
    where
        created_at between
            '2022-12-01' and '2022-12-10' and
        terminal_id like '111%'
```

How to write query to get this output:

| 911like | 111like |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 25 |

Answer (score 1):

This is done using count("expression"). This will count when the expression is true

```
select count(case when terminal_id like '911%'  
                  then name
               end)  as [911like]
       ,count(case when terminal_id like '111%'  
                  then name
               end)  as [111like]
   from table
 where created_at between '2022-12-01' and '2022-12-10'
```

Comment: Square brackets are not supported by MySQL

Answer (score 1):

More simplified:

```
select sum(terminal_id like '911%') as 911like,
       sum(terminal_id like '111%') as 111like
from my_table
where created_at between '2022-12-01' and '2022-12-10';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/PqdCP0Fq